# Creating 2x1 matrix system

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I have created 2x1 matrix system in which one person if donating money and after donation he is receiving money from two persons. I am trying to create a situation where one one person comes in the system for the first time (after signup), system will check either is there any person in the system is available to receive money from that person or not, if there is any person then i am checking either that person has already got two payments or not if the person got 2 payments that system will check for the next person in the system and will go for the process again to check the person either he has received twice or not. 
Now the issue is that system is only checking 2 persons like if the system is finding one person and that person already revived twice payments system is going for next one but if the next has received then system should go to the next one and so on unless he finds user or no user. But my system is only going up to two persons and i do not know how should i create a loop so that system check for entire users in the database.

```
public function allotDonar($id) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
    $currentDate = strtotime($date);
    $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*1);
    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", $futureDate);
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", strtotime('+30 hours'));

    $get = $this -> db -> query("Select user.id, user.super, user.name, 
user.canRecieve, user.active, user.blocked, user_packages.packageID, user.type, 
user_packages.userID from (Select user.id AS USERID, canRecieve, type, super, 
status, packageID, active from user JOIN user_packages ON user.id='$id' AND 
user.type='0' AND user.super='0' AND user.canRecieve='0' AND user.active='1' AND 
user_packages.userID=user.id AND user_packages.status='1') AS DONOR JOIN user ON 
user.id!='$id' AND user.canRecieve='1' AND user.active='1' AND user.blocked='0' 
AND user.type='0'  AND user.super='0' JOIN user_packages ON 
user.id=user_packages.userID AND user_packages.status='1' AND 
user_packages.packageID=DONOR.packageID ORDER BY user.id ASC");
    if($get -> num_rows() > 0) {
        $UserInfo = $get -> row();
        $key = $get -> result();
        $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND reciever_id=?";
        $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $UserInfo -> id));
        // return $query -> result();
        if($query -> num_rows() >= 2) {
            // return 'Persons';
            // if user cycle has not been completed but user has tow recievings in the table then again search fot the next user in the array
            $nexPerson = current(array_slice($key, array_search($key, array_keys($key)) + 1, 1));
            if(!empty($nexPerson)) {
                $nextPersonID = $nexPerson -> id;
                // check if next pserons has paid money or not
                $checkIfNextPaid = $this -> db -> query("Select * from user where canRecieve='1'");
                if($checkIfNextPaid -> num_rows() > 0) {
                    $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND reciever_id=?";
                    $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($nexPerson -> packageID, $nexPerson -> id));
                    // return $query -> result();
                    if($query -> num_rows() >= 2) {
                        //$this -> allotDonar($id);
                    }
                    else {

                        $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND donarID=?";
                        $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $id));
                        if($query -> num_rows() >= 1) {
                        }
                        else {
                        // $currentID = $UserInfo -> id;
                            $allotDonar = $this -> db -> insert('donar', array('donarID'    =>  $id, 'reciever_id'  =>  $nexPerson -> id, 'packageID'    =>  $nexPerson -> packageID, 'date_added'    =>  $date, 'date_expiry'    =>  $endDate, 'wait_time' =>  $formatDate, 'wait_start' =>  $date));
                            return $this -> db -> insert_id();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND donarID=?";
            $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $id));
            if($query -> num_rows() >= 1) {
            }
            else {
                // if the rows of the user are less then 2 record then simply insert the erecord of the user                  
                $allotDonar = $this -> db -> insert('donar', array('donarID'    =>  $id, 'reciever_id'  =>  $UserInfo -> id, 'packageID'    =>  $UserInfo -> packageID, 'date_added'    =>  $date, 'date_expiry'    =>  $endDate, 'wait_time' =>  $formatDate, 'wait_start' =>  $date));
                return $this -> db -> insert_id();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return 'No person found';
    }
```

Please help me to make this system check for entire users in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
public function allotDonar($id) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
    $currentDate = strtotime($date);
    $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*1);
    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", $futureDate);
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", strtotime('+30 hours'));

    $get = $this -> db -> query("Select user.id, user.super, user.name, user.canRecieve, user.active, user.blocked, user_packages.packageID, user.type, user_packages.userID from (Select user.id AS USERID, canRecieve, type, super, status, packageID, active from user JOIN user_packages ON user.id='$id' AND user.type='0' AND user.super='0' AND user.canRecieve='0' AND user.active='1' AND user_packages.userID=user.id AND user_packages.status='1') AS DONOR JOIN user ON user.id!='$id' AND user.canRecieve='1' AND user.active='1' AND user.blocked='0' AND user.type='0'  AND user.super='0' JOIN user_packages ON user.id=user_packages.userID AND user_packages.status='1' AND user_packages.packageID=DONOR.packageID ORDER BY user.id ASC");
    if($get -> num_rows() > 0) {
        $UserInfo = $get -> row();
        $key = $get -> result();
        $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND reciever_id=?";
        $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $UserInfo -> id));
        // return $query -> result();
        if($query -> num_rows() >= 2) {
            // return 'Persons';
            // if user cycle has not been completed but user has tow recievings in the table then again search fot the next user in the array
            $next = 1;
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($key); $i++) {
                $nexPerson = current(array_slice($key, array_search($key, array_keys($key)) + $i, 1));
                $found = $this -> findNextPerson($UserInfo, $nexPerson, $id);
            }
        }
        else {
            $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND donarID=?";
            $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $id));
            if($query -> num_rows() >= 1) {
                // return false
            }
            else {
                // if the rows of the user are less then 2 record then simply insert the erecord of the user                  
                $allotDonar = $this -> db -> insert('donar', array('donarID'    =>  $id, 'reciever_id'  =>  $UserInfo -> id, 'packageID'    =>  $UserInfo -> packageID, 'date_added'    =>  $date, 'date_expiry'    =>  $endDate, 'wait_time' =>  $formatDate, 'wait_start' =>  $date));
                return $this -> db -> insert_id();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return 'No person found';
    }

}

function findNextPerson($UserInfo, $nexPerson, $id) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
    $currentDate = strtotime($date);
    $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*1);
    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", $futureDate);
    $endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a", strtotime('+30 hours'));

    if(!empty($nexPerson)) {
        $nextPersonID = $nexPerson -> id;
        // check if next pserons has paid money or not
        $checkIfNextPaid = $this -> db -> query("Select * from user where canRecieve='1'");
        if($checkIfNextPaid -> num_rows() > 0) {
            $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND reciever_id=?";
            $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($nexPerson -> packageID, $nexPerson -> id));
            // return $query -> result();
            if($query -> num_rows() >= 2) {
                return 'Go back';
            }
            else {
                $sql = "Select * from donar where packageID=? AND donarID=?";
                $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($UserInfo -> packageID, $id));
                if($query -> num_rows() >= 1) {
                }
                else {
                // $currentID = $UserInfo -> id;
                    $allotDonar = $this -> db -> insert('donar', array('donarID'    =>  $id, 'reciever_id'  =>  $nexPerson -> id, 'packageID'    =>  $nexPerson -> packageID, 'date_added'    =>  $date, 'date_expiry'    =>  $endDate, 'wait_time' =>  $formatDate, 'wait_start' =>  $date));
                    return $this -> db -> insert_id();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```